# Test Dependencies between PHP unit tests in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am working on `Laravel 5.7` and i'd like to ask you a question regarding the PHPUnit testing.

I have a test class, let's say `ProductControllerTest.php`, with two methods `testProductSoftDelete()` and `testProductPermanentlyDelete()`. I want to use the annotation `@depends` in the testProductPermanentlyDelete() in order to soft-delete first a product and then get the product id and proceed to permanently deletion test. The problem here is that the `DatabaseTransaction` trait runs the transactions in every test (method) execution. I need to start the transaction before all the tests of my ProductControllerTest class and then rollback the transaction at the end of all tests. Do you have any ideas? From what i have searched from the web nothing worked properly.

```
public function testProductSoftDelete()
{
   some code

   return $product_id;
}

/**
* @depends testProductSoftDelete
*/
public function testProductPermanentlyDelete($product_id)
{
   code to test permanently deletion of the product with id $product_id.
   There is a business logic behind that needs to soft delete first a 
   product before you permanently delete it.

}
```

Does the following make sense?

```
    namespace Tests\App\Controllers\Product;

    use Tests\DatabaseTestCase;
    use Tests\TestRequestsTrait;

    /**
     * @group Coverage
     * @group App.Controllers
     * @group App.Controllers.Product
     *
     * Class ProductControllerTest
     *
     * @package Tests\App\Controllers\Product
     */

    class ProductControllerTest extends DatabaseTestCase
    {
        use TestRequestsTrait;

        public function testSoftDelete()
        {
            $response = $this->doProductSoftDelete('9171448');
            $response
                ->assertStatus(200)
                ->assertSeeText('Product sof-deleted successfully');
        }


        public function testUnlink()
        {
            $this->doProductSoftDelete('9171448');
            $response = $this->actingAsSuperAdmin()->delete('/pages/admin/management/product/unlink/9171448');

            $response
                ->assertStatus(200)
                ->assertSeeText('Product unlinked successfully');
        }
    }


    namespace Tests;

    trait TestRequestsTrait
    {
        /**
         * Returns the response
         *
         * @param $product_id
         * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse
         */
        protected function doProductSoftDelete($product_id)
        {
            $response = $this->actingAsSuperAdmin()->delete('/pages/admin/management/product/soft-delete/'.$product_id);
            return $response;
        }

    }

    namespace Tests;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

    abstract class DatabaseTestCase extends TestCase
    {

        use CreatesApplication;
        use DatabaseTransactions;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate function to execute the same behavior twice:

```
public function testProductSoftDelete()
{
    doSoftDelete();
}

public function testProductPermanentlyDelete()
{
    doSoftDelete();
    doPermanentDelete();
}
```

Your case isn't a case of test dependency, but what you really want to do is to check if a soft deleted can be permanent deleted (or something like that).
Creating a dependency, in this case, will increase complexity of the test.
It's usually better to mount the test scenario from scratch (data/objects), then execute the logic, and then test if the actual scenario is the expected.

Comment: With this approach, i will execute the doSoftDelete() test code twice which is something i need to avoid. I dont know if i can perform depends functionality. Maybe, this solutuon is the only option here. Thank for your kind response.

Comment: The other solution would be to not use `DatabaseTransaction` trait in this file, but manage to clean whenever you need. If you use in some BaseClass like TestCase, then you need to remove from there and add in every class you are using.

Comment: Or you can inherit from some Class tha use `DatabaseTransaction` trait, and in this class you don't. The code you become more complex, though.